# How to select from multiple associated arrays and display them?

Tags: mysql, arrays, associative

I have a page about sending requests for different subjects and levels to teachers. For this end I have a separate area for the teachers, where they can log in and see all the requests that have been sent and which match their particular subjects and levels. Please excuse my english.

So I save the name, address etc. of the request in one database table (since it is unique) and for each subject that someone requests one row is inserted into another database table. The teachers and their subjects are saved in another database table, which are all connected to each other by foreign keys and filtered by WHERE commands to check if the request matches the teachers subjects/levels. Now this functions.

But I have trouble displaying the requests the right way: I want to display these requests by showing the address of the request only one time and to create a table data/cell (td) for each subject/level combination (e.g. if one client asks for 5. grade German and English and for 7. grade German and Latin it should display the address and name one time, after that two cells with 5. grade German and English and after that the cell/table data for the 7. grade German and Latin).

Here is the code I use for the JOIN (works perfectly for filtering and getting the results, translated it into english):

```
SELECT
   request.street,
   classes.class,
   subjects.subject,
   schools.school,
   requests_subjects.description,
   teachers.name 
FROM
   requests_subjects  
LEFT JOIN
   subjects  
      ON  requests_subjects.subject_id = subjects.subject_id  
LEFT JOIN
   classes  
      ON  classes.class_id = requests_subjects.class_id  
LEFT JOIN
   schools  
      ON  schools.school_id = requests_subjects.schule_id  
LEFT JOIN
   requests  
      ON  requests_subjects.request_id = request.request_id  
LEFT JOIN
   requests_subjects  
      ON  requests_subjects.subject_id = teachers_subjects.subject_id  
LEFT JOIN
   teachers  
      ON  teachers_subjects.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id  
WHERE
   teachers.name = '".ucfirst($_SESSION['user'])."' 
   AND requests_subjects.status_id = 1 
   AND lteachers_subjects.status_id = 1 
   AND requests_subjects.class_id <= teachers_subjects.class_id
```

And I currently use the following table code for displaying the results (also shortened and translated into english). I basically wanted to use the foreach loop to create for each different class a particular table data/cell -> so if two different classes/levels are adressed, two table data are created, each containing the subjects that are requested for that class/level:

```
print "<table> \n";
$result = $pdo->query($order);
```

First row for the table heads:

```
print " <tr> \n";
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print " <th>Where?</th> \n";
  foreach ($row['class']){   
      print "<th>Which subjects and which level?</th> \n";
  }
  </tr> \n";
```

And here the foreach loop, which should create only one tablerow for each adress and one table data/cell for each subjects/classes combination:

```
    foreach ($row['street']){
        print " <tr> \n";
        if ($nr <= 1){
            print "<td>".$row['street']."</td>";
            foreach ($row['class']){  
               print "<td>" . $row['subject'] . " for the " 
                        . $row['class'] . " " . $row['school']
                   . "</td>";
            }
        }
        $nr + 1;  
    }
    print " </tr> \n";
}
print "</table> \n";
```

Comment: Where do the tables teachers_subjects and lteachers_subjects come from, and did you mean to join requests_subjects twice? (either way, might be an idea to learn about aliases). Maybe something got lost in transalation

Comment: Hey Jorge, the JOIN code was translated into english, it is possible that there is a mistake in it - but the JOIN code is not the problem, it should just help for understanding the background of my request. It is not requests_subjects it should be "teachers_subjects". Problem is that I don't know how to get the adress one time (even though it is selected multiple times by the JOINs because there is one row for every requested subject) and displaying in one row together with only one table data/cell per subject/class combination :/ greetings!

Comment: Sorry, if you are facing translation problem. Try doing the foreach ($row['class']) outside and foreach ($row['street']) inside of it. Because, street/address is always unique and has only one row in database table but there can be multiple rows of classes as per the request

Comment: Hi, if I do the foreach ($row['class']) I get `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' in /var/www/xxx/html/lehrer.php on line 122` . And if I use foreach ($row['class'] AS $request) I get  `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/xxx/html/lehrer.php on line 122`. The street/address is not unique after the table have joined, so there is e.g. three or four times the same street/address in the connected table if the same street/address request asks for three or four different subjects/classes. I basically want to select adress one time and one td for each class